# Using variable in an if / else statement

Tags: jquery

I am creating a variable that is equal to the text of a `<a>` that has been clicked on, and then use the variable in an if / else statement but cant get it to work.  I know the variable is right, and I know the function works because I can replace it with a "whatever.html" and it work.  However I cant get the variable to work in its place:

```
   $(".themenu a").click(function(){
          var stuff = $(this);
          if (stuff == "Home"){
                 $.get("main.html", function(data){
                 $(".content").append(data);
          }, "html");
   }
```

Comment: If you want html to appear in your question quote it with the ` character (I've updated your question to do this).

Comment: I guess you have to change the second row to `var stuff = $(this).text();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(this);` will get you a jQuery object, not the text of it, so that won't be equal to `"Home"`. Use

```
var stuff = $(this).text();
```

or

```
var stuff = $(this).html();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are setting your `stuff` variable to reference the jQuery object returned by `$(this)`, when what you really want is the text of the element in that jQuery object like so:

```
var stuff = $(this).text();
```

EDIT: note that in your click handler `this` will be equal to the `<a>` element you could also do this:

```
var stuff = this.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector selects the `<a>` node, which is an object. If you want to use it for comparison, you first have to get the value, ID or content of that tag.

```
var stuff = $(this);
```

Now, `stuff` contains a DOM object representing the `<a href="url">Home</a>` element.
What you want is to extract the bit between the tags.

```
var innerStuff = stuff.text();
```

Or of course, directly:

```
var stuff = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `var stuff = $(this).text();` instead.

Comment: +1 to balance the unexplained -1 (don't know why this was voted down when it is correct, though it is a duplicate answer).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var stuff = $(this).text();
```

Comment: +1 to balance the unexplained -1 (don't know why this was voted down when it is correct, though it is a duplicate answer).